# Win Phone 7 quiz app

Tags: windows-phone-7

Could any1 please suggest a method by which i can store all my questions , Multiple Choice answers and the correct answer. So that i can call them and then display in a text box and radio buttons . And as when the user answers a question correctly i should be able to move to the next question.

This was my approach. Used data serialization, created a class with Data memebers which will store question id , questions and answers. then created an object for it in while page is loading. But i am unable to display the questions. Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the number of questions, you might find it easier and faster to use a [local database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202860%28v=vs.92%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I am a little confused at your approach.  Serialization by itself doesnt actually persist data.  Perhaps that is your problem.  I have found that storing the XML to IsolatedStorage is one of the easier ways to persist data.

I created an IsolatedStorage class that looks like this for saving an XDocument object.

```
  public static void SaveDataToIsolatedStorage(string filePath, FileMode fileMode, XDocument xDoc)
        {
            using (IsolatedStorageFile storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                using (IsolatedStorageFileStream location = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(filePath, fileMode, storage))
                {
                    System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(location);
                    xDoc.Save(file);
                }
            }
        }
```

Here is my reader.

```
   private static XDocument ReadDataFromIsolatedStorageXmlDoc()
        {
            using (IsolatedStorageFile storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                if (!storage.FileExists(filePath))
                {
                    return new XDocument();
                }

                using (var isoFileStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(filePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, storage))
                {
                    using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(isoFileStream))
                    {
                        return XDocument.Load(reader);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```